# How do I find the list of inner child tagnames using the object of Parent Tag

Tags: java, selenium, html-table

Can anyone help me to find out the list of child tagnames using reference of parent tagname.

In a table I have list of rows and columns which means each row has 14 columns and each column has list of inner tags like span, span, input. Now I need to find the list of items under column `td[11]` for which I have written the below code:

```
 element=driver.findElement(shopviewtableid);
        items=element.findElements(shopviewrow);
        if(items.size()>0) {
            for(WebElement ele:items) {
              columnvalues=ele.findElements(shopviewcolumn);
              for(WebElement item:columnvalues) {
                 System.out.println("Inside Tag name of each column"+item..toString());
```

In the above code I am passing table `id` in `shopviewtable id` and `tagname tr` for `shopviewrow` and `xpath //td[11]` for `shopviewcolumn`. Now after fetching the `td[11]` for each row again I am fetching the list of items under `td[11]`

```
for(WebElement item:columnvalues) {
  System.out.println("Inside Tag name of each column"+item..toString());" .
```

Here under `td[11]` I have three items with `tagname` as `span,span,input`. **PFA screenshot** How do I get name of these tags from the list[enter image description here]

Tried using `item.getTagname()` for each item but it displays `td` as `tagname` and not the name of the element inside the `td[11]`.

It would be great if anyone could help me on this issue.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAG3k.png]

Here is my Html structure:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="width: 11%;" class="jqnoDetails">
<span id="detailsForm:j_id_5q:0:minQuantity" class="hidden">1</span>
<span id="detailsForm:j_id_5q:0:incQuantity" class="hidden">1</span>
<span id="detailsForm:j_id_5q:0:originalQuantity" class="hidden">1.0000</span>
<input id="detailsForm:j_id_5q:0:quantity" name="detailsForm:j_id_5q:0:quantity" type="text" value="1" min="0" inc="1" onblur="PrimeFaces.bcn(this,event,[function(event){handleQuantityChanged(this); updatePrice($(this), 11.23);},function(event){jsf.ajax.request('detailsForm:j_id_5q:0:quantity',event,{execute:'@this ',render:'@this ','CLIENT_BEHAVIOR_RENDERING_MODE':'OBSTRUSIVE','javax.faces.behavior.event':'blur'})}])" style="width: 85%;" aria-required="true" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all jqQuantityInput textCenter" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
</td>
```

Comment: Can you update the relevant `HTML` as `Formatted Text` within the question area?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have the mechanism to find the cell using iteration as shown. Now try to get all child elements of particular grid cell using XPath like this -

```
List<WebElement> childElements =item.findElements(By.xpath(".//child::*"));
 //try even (".//*") as XPath to get the child elements
```

once you have a list of elements, you can iterate using for loop to get required tag or another data [getAttribute](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) method of WebElement.

Comment: Thanks.But if I use .//child::* it returns all the child elements more than 1000 items..In my case I have Only one row with 14 columns.So it should stop once it reaches the end of the row and the 14 th column.Is that rite/

Comment: How do I fetch the items the child elements which should stop once it reaches end of the row and the column.

Comment: @RajeshKumar As I mentioned, you need to use for loop, the way  you have used to select the particular cell and then try to get child element of that cell and not the whole page `cell.findElements(By.xpath(".//child::*"))` and then you would have child elements of cell

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code to get the tag names of each element inside a cell.

```
     element=driver.findElement(shopviewtableid);
        items=element.findElements(shopviewrow);
        if(items.size()>0) {
            for(WebElement ele:items) {
              columnvalues=ele.findElements(shopviewcolumn);
              for(WebElement item:columnvalues) {
                 System.out.println("Inside Tag name of each column");

                 insideElements=item.findElements(By.xpath("//*");
                 for(WebElement ele:insideElements)
                {
                 System.out.println("Inside Element tag:"+ ele.getTagName();
                }
           }
```